# Ошибка сохранения сложной структуры в файле

Tags: c++

[image: Вот такое в отладчике.]

[image: и такое]

```
else if (a == 2)
    {
        ifstream fout;
        fout.open(path);
        if (!fout.is_open()) {
            cout << "Ошибка открытия файла!";
        }
        else {
            cout << "Введите нужную вам станцию: ";
            string station;
            cin >> station;
            TrainInfo train_out;
            while (fout.read((char*)&train_out, sizeof(TrainInfo)))
            {
                if (station == train_out.destination_station)
                {
                    cout << "Номер поезда: " << train_out.number << endl;
                    cout << "Станция отправления: " << train_out.departure_station << endl;
                    cout << "Станция назначения: " << train_out.destination_station << endl;
                    cout << "Время отправления: " << train_out.departure_time << endl;
                    cout << "Время прибытия: " << train_out.arrival_time << endl;
                    cout << "Тип поезда: " << train_out.type << endl << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        fout.close();
```

Просто вылетает приложение при выборе второго пункта меню после ввода нужной станции. Что не так?(в С++ очень большой новичок) Знаю,что проблема в этой строчке `while (fout.read((char*)&train_out, sizeof(TrainInfo)))`, но как ее исправить?

Comment: Что такое `TrainInfo`? И почему вы считаете, что поверх переменной `train_out` можно записать строку? Вы бы лучше текст программы привели полностью вместо этих картинок в палитре вырви глаз.

Comment: TrainInfo - это структура. `struct TrainInfo {

 int number;
 string departure_station;
 string destination_station;
 int departure_time;
 int arrival_time;
 string type;
};` Как мне тогда продлить цикл пока не прочитаются все объекты?

Comment: Ну понятно тогда почему вылетает, а что вы хотели получить-то?

Comment: Объясните,пожалуйста, почему,а то мне не понятно)

Comment: Ну вам же в ответе объяснили. Не скажу, правда, что сам въехал в эту обширную аллегорию, но я и не пытался, а вот вам бы стоило попробовать понять. Нельзя экземпляр класса просто брать и перезаписывать какими-то левыми данными. Да и вообще любую переменную не стоит произвольно перезаписывать мусором, ничего хорошего из этого выйти не может. Вы что хотели добиться этой командой? У вас же какая-то цель имелась, когда вы это писали?

Comment: Мне нужно просто считать все объекты записанные в файл. Не знаю как иначе.

Comment: Ну вы же когда выводите, то не пишете `write((char*)&train_out, sizeof(TrainInfo))`, а выводите каждое поле отдельно, с преобразованием в строку где надо. А при вводе вдруг ничего не знаете. Как-то не верится, скорее проще загрузить кого-нибудь, чем самому подумать.

Comment: Написать `std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &, TrainInfo &)` и не мучаться.

Answer (score 4):

Ну нельзя читать/писать вот так -

```
fout.read((char*)&train_out, sizeof(TrainInfo))
```

что-то, кроме простейших структур! Вряд ли у вас TrainInfo - plain old data (POD). Там же наверняка что-то есть не совсем фундаментальное :)

Рассказывать, как конкретно исправить ситуацию - без знания, что и как у вас объявлено - не получится. Общая идея - ну вот тот же `string` - это класс, в объекте которого указатель, а само содержимое - где-то в памяти.

Получается у вас примерно так - жена говорит собраться в отпуск и в машину в багажник сложить, ну, там, матрас надувной, палатку, мангал и шампуры - ну, в общем, барахло. Вы в багажник кладете бумажки с надписями "Матрас - на антресолях", "Палатка - на балконе" (ваши указатели) и т.д. Так вот сохраняете в багажник/файл...

По приезду на место читаете - вынимаете из багажника бумажки с надписями, где что лежит. Но хуже того, что шкаф теперь совсем другой, балкон тоже, так что втык от жены - это примерно и есть результат вот такого хранения и попытки раскрыть палатку, которой нет...

Поройтесь здесь, на сайте - тут эта тема возникала не раз.

Comment: Прекрасная метафора с бумажками в багажнике

Comment: а почему это они вдруг стали другими?

Comment: Потому что вы переехали в другой город :) Например, старый объект удален, память переписана - это при записи и чтении файла в одном запуске программы. А если вы записали файл, а потом читаете его при другом запуске программы - то в памяти по этому адресу вообще может быть что-то запрещенное :) - и уж точно не содержимое старой строки, которому просто неоткуда взяться...