# Ошибка при чтении из файла: "Попытка чтения или запись в защищённую память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена"

Tags: c++, файлы

При попытке чтения из бинарного файла во время работы самой программы (компилируется всё без проблем) открывается файл xmemory0 и выскакивает ошибка с текстом: "Попытка чтения или запись в защищённую память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена".

Функция, из-за которой происходит ошибка:

```
System::Void MyForm::SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
    {
        fstream Usrs;
        Usrs.open("Users.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
        StructForReg Perenos;
        Usrs.read((char*)& Perenos, sizeof(StructForReg));
    }
```

Вот описание структуры StructForReg:

```
public struct StructForReg   //Структура для регистрации
    {
        string Username; //Логин
        string Password; //Пароль
        float Balance = 0;
        string Bisquit;
        string Filling;
        string Glaze;
        string Trappings;
        string Layers;
    };
```

Comment: К чему, по-вашему, должно привести выражение `(char*)& Perenos`?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/910758/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5

Comment: Это единственное написание, при котором чтение через данную функцию у меня компилируется. Прошу предоставить пример правильного написания. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Приведите описание `StructForReg`.

Comment: Используйте json или xml для сохранения файлов, чтобы избежать проблем с сохранением. Если не хотите использовать их, то можете заюзать base64 (но только для простых структур)

Comment: Andrej Levkovitch, можно разжевать, пожалуйста, с примерами использования? Я новичок и не могу понять, о чём речь

Comment: @Irenne записывать в эту структуру  так нельзя, т.к. она не тривиальная и информация строк в ней зранитсяв отдельных блоках памяти. Т.е. она не POD.  Считывать каждую строку и поле придется по отдельности!

Comment: @Irenne гуглите tinyxml